# PHP MYSQL SELECT query parameter includes an ampersand(&)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO prepared statements.  I am passing in a string and returning the record from MYSQL. I am passing three variables to the method.

The query returns nothing.  If I perform the same query in phpmyadmin it returns all the correct data.  I believe it is the ampersand(&) in the $team variable but, don't know I to work around it.  I am not using a link and it is not a form element.  It is a straight call to the method.
The values of the three parameters are

```
    $season = '2018-19';
    $league = 20;
    $team = "Texas A&M University-Kingsville";
```

Here is my method:

```
    public static function getTeamGames($season, $league, $team){

        $conn = parent::connect();            
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM rfw_games WHERE season = :season && 
            league = :league && home = :team";
        try {
            $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $st->bindValue( ":season", $season, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $st->bindValue( ":team", $team, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $st->bindValue( ":league", $league, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $st->execute();

            $games = array();
            foreach ( $st->fetchAll() as $row ) {
                $games[] = new Game( $row );
            }
            parent::disconnect( $conn);
            return $games;
        } catch (PDOException $e ) {
            parent::disconnect( $conn );
            die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

    $weeklyGames = Game::getTeamGames( $season, $league, $tName );
```

I really appreciate the help of everyone.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: It doesn't give an error

Comment: Then you tried dumping the result?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue.

I had to use html_entity_decode on the $team parameter.

I changed my method to the following:

```
        public static function getTeamGames($season, $league, $team){
          $dTeam = html_entity_decode($team);

          $conn = parent::connect();              
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM rfw_games WHERE season = :season && league = :league && home = :team";

          try {
            $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
            $st->bindValue( ":season", $season, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $st->bindValue( ":team", $dTeam, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $st->bindValue( ":league", $league, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $st->execute();
            $games = array();
            foreach ( $st->fetchAll() as $row ) {
              $games[] = new Game( $row );
            }
            parent::disconnect( $conn);
            return $games;
          } catch (PDOException $e ) {
            parent::disconnect( $conn );
            die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
          }
       }
```